# Prerequisites for Rotman's Introduction to Homological Algebra

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

I was curious as to what the proper prerequisites would be to be able to properly read through Rotman's text "An Introduction to Homological Algebra". I'm wondering if Module theory is part of the prerequisites. Also considering the length of Rotman's Text what chapters would be the best to cover to get to homology theory and Ext and Tor?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular book but I can't imagine that the basics of module theory would not be prerequisites.

Comment: Hm, well, the book itself seems pretty clear on the topic. The first lines of chapter 2 (entitled "Modules") say: We assume that much of this section is familiar to most readers, and so our account is written to refresh one's memory."  So... read that and you'll know what you need to go learn.

Comment: I don't have the book but I think the Dummit and Foote sections on modules and homological algebra are a good starting point/reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just fetched the first edition (hardbound, 1979) off the shelf: 
On the fourth page (out of 376) you will find *"Recall that a left $R$-module is an ..."*, furthermore the first section in Chapter 2 is entitled *"Modules"*. Thus modules are not supposed to be prerequisites.

J. J. Rotman explicitly addresses the fastest way towards Homology in "How to read this book" (this section is contained in the second edition of the book), namely skipping chapters 2 to 5, but he does not recommend it. 
A sort of triple jump touching chapter 1, chapter 2, and the projective and injective ingredients in chapter 3 may be a satisfactory path for you.